# reading URLs containing "æøå" with readLines, R

Tags: r, url, encoding, readlines

Im trying to read the source code of a website with weather data. The url contains scandinavian letters (æøå). Choosing encoding "UTF-8" does not work in the readLines function. Any idea what could solve the problem?

```
source <- readLines( "https://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Oslo/Oslo/Bygdøy_målestasjon/almanakk.html?dato=2018-01-08", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: code works here...  note: it is a (very) bad idea to choose variable-names that are also (base) R functions... (i.e. source)

Comment: This likely depends on Håkon's system, which I would guess is Windows, and Wimpel's, which I would guess is not.

Comment: It worked for me with this url: `p <- readLines( "https://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Oslo/Oslo/Bygd%c3%b8y_m%c3%a5lestasjon/almanakk.html", encoding = "UTF-8")`